# PHP, Bootstrap - user/password validation

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm learning PHP and Bootstrap and I'm running into an issue when trying to validate my input fields.

Before I added Bootstrap I was able to validate the form but now it doesn't work.. does PHP and Bootstrap not work together for some reason in this fashion?

Particularly my page doesn't seem to be validating on the POST.

Does Bootstrap have the capability to validate user input directly???

I'm a bit confused and if I'm mixing technology's that shouldn't .. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/login.php'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
//initialize the session and verify user is logged in and allowed to view site
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}else{
    $qryUSER_ID=$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
}

//print_r($_POST);
//print_r($_SESSION);
//print_r($_GET);

?>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$usernameErr = $passwordErr = $password_confirmErr = $password_matchErr = "";
$username = $password = $password_confirm = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameErr = "User name is required";
  } else {
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    // check if username only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_.A-Z-' ]*$/",$username)) {
      $usernameErr = "Only letters, numbers and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
  } else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["password_confirm"])) {
    $password_confirmErr = "Password confirm is required";
  } else {
    $password_confirm = test_input($_POST["password_confirm"]);
  }
  
  if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_confirm']) {
    $password_matchErr = "Passwords must match";   
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Skins Game-Add User</title>
</head>
<body>  

<form method="post" action="dtlprocess.php"> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label colspan="3" class="font-weight-bold"><h2>Add New User</h2></label>  
    </div>
    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">User Name:</label><span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username);?>">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password:</label><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password);?>">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password Confirm:</label><span class="error"><?php echo $password_matchErr;?></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirm" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password_confirm);?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="addUser" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" name="frmback" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button></td>
    </div>      
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The dreaded `test_input()` again. Do not us that, instead avoid [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) and use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: They dont bother each other, but exactly what does "Does not work" mean

Comment: Not working meaning that the user input isn't being validated... I think I've tracked it down to the FORM ACTION since its not submitting to itself for validation.. action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>'

Comment: Also, test_input()... is this not a "Safe" approach to getting user input to be added to a DB?? .... $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, password, active) VALUES ('$dd_username', '$dd_password', 'A') ") or die($mysqli->error);

Comment: You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: The problem I was experiencing was that the "Action" for the form was not firing the code... so I had to sightly re-write the code to accommodate a new insert statement using prepared statements.. I think I've got it going with the helpful nudges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs across a similar problem in the future... here is the modified code using a paramater mysqli.

It seems like Bootstrap should have some built in functionality for validating Usernames and validating passwords, therefore eliminating some of the php code.

Thanks,

````
<?php require_once('../Connections/login.php'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
//initialize the session and verify user is logged in and allowed to view site
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}else{
    $qryUSER_ID=$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
}

//print_r($_POST);
//print_r($_SESSION);
//print_r($_GET);

?>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$usernameErr = $passwordErr = $password_confirmErr = $password_matchErr = "";
$username = $password = $password_confirm = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameErr = "User name is required";
  } else {
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    // check if username only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_.A-Z-' ]*$/",$username)) {
      $usernameErr = "Only letters, numbers and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
  } else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["password_confirm"])) {
    $password_confirmErr = "Password confirm is required";
  } else {
    $password_confirm = test_input($_POST["password_confirm"]);
  }
  
  if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_confirm']) {
    $password_matchErr = "Passwords must match"; 
  } else {
        //Past the validation checks, add new user
        //this also tests if the user exists before trying to add user since it will throw an error
        if (isset($_POST['addUser'])){
            
            //query if user exists already
            $checkuser = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
            $checkuser->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
            $checkuser->execute();
            //row count will be > 0 if user exists
            $checkrows= $checkuser->get_result();   
            $checkuser->close();

            if($checkrows->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "User already exists";
                exit();
            }else{
                //Add new user since they do not exist
                $activeuser = 'A';
                $addnewuser = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, password, active) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                $addnewuser->bind_param("sss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $activeuser);
                $addnewuser->execute();
                $addnewuser->close();
                
                header("Location: summary.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
  }

}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
    .font10{font-size: 10px;}
</style>

  <title>Skins Game-Add User</title>
</head>
<body>  

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label colspan="3" class="font-weight-bold"><h2>Add New User</h2></label>  
    </div>
    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">User Name:</label><label class="error font10"><?php echo $usernameErr;?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password:</label><span class="error font10"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password Confirm:</label><span class="error font10"><?php echo $password_matchErr;?></span>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirm" value="<?php echo $password_confirm;?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="addUser" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" name="frmback" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button></td>
    </div>      
</form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: ___therefore eliminating some of the php code___ You can Never rely on validation done in the clients browser. It can be turned off or circumnavigated or I could fake a POST to the script when never having been near your page. You should always repeat any user input validation in the server code.

Comment: ALthough I am not sure what you have removed here :)

Comment: The change was made to the form action... action="dtlprocess.php". this wasn't firing the sequence to validate the user input until I changed it to action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"

Comment: I am still experiencing an issue when validating the POST, the EMPTY() function doesn't appear to be correctly identifying a blank or empty for a username when the form is submitted. The POST looks like this with nothing entered for username or passwords...  Array ( [username] => [password] => [password_confirm] => [addUser] => SUBMIT ) and is not being caught for an empty username, password.. Does $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] somehow modify the form fields when submitting to the POST causing this false positive???

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: Code is a bit of a mess. 1) You validate all the inputs, and if you find an error you create a variable with the error message. You then IGNORE those error messages and do the update regardless. 2) you call `test_input()` (**totally unnecessary, and a dangerous function**) on all the inputs, placing the results in variables. You then execute the BIND using the $_POST variable (uncleansed)

Comment: Also you are storing _Plain Text Passwords_ V.Bad practice. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. since I'm new to PHP I'm trying to follow the following example: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/php-required-field. I didn't think I strayed too far from that example except for the insert section after the password compare... ?? Is the test_input() moot because of the htmlspecialchars() on the PHP_SELF?.... "You then execute the BIND using the $_POST variable (uncleansed)" - isn't that the function of the htmlspecialchars() to cleanse the POST???

Comment: It can be, but not in this situation

Comment: I would find a better site. A training site that advertises other (better) training sites on every page I think should tell you all you need to know about its quality, and the reson for its existance

Comment: Last question on the subject... does the following tut (https://www.studentstutorial.com/php/signup-login-form-in-php-mysql) check the boxes on server side processing & MD5?? Although, I don't see how they are cleansing the $POST for the user information... if they are at all?

Comment: That one is even WORSE

Comment: Please never __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Also `extract($_POST);` in global scope is a complete security nightmare

Comment: Yikes! do you have any suggestions then?? Much appreciate the guidance here..

Comment: We are not supposed to recommend tutorials/code etc. My opinion may not be others opinions on what is good/best SORRY

Answer (score -1):

Use an array of errors instead of blank variables.

You can use validation like this just create a file for this:

**validation.php**:

```php
        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
        $login = test_input($_POST['login']);
        $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
        $password = test_input($_POST['password']);
        $password_confirm = test_input($_POST['password_confirm']);
        $succ = [];//old value of inputes will be stored here

        if(empty($name)){
            $errors['name'] = 'Name required';
        }else{
            $succ['name'] = $name;
        }

        if(empty($login)){
            $errors['login'] = 'Login required';
        }else{
            $succ['login'] = $login;
        }

        if(empty($email)){
            $errors['email'] = 'Email required';
        }else{
            $succ['email'] = $email;
        }

        if(empty($password)){
            $errors['password'] = 'password required';
        }

        if($password_confirm != $password){
            $errors['password_confirm'] = 'Passwords are not equal';
        }
    if(isset($errors)){
            $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
            $_SESSION['succ'] = $succ;
            header("Location: index.php");
            die;
        }else{
            header("Location: index.php")
        }
```

and add into form attribute `action="validation.php"` and add to the top of your file:

**index.php**

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
    $errors = $_SESSION['errors'];//execute errors from the session
    $succ = $_SESSION['succ'];
    unset($_SESSION['succ']);
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);//delete all errrors from the session
}
```

And then you can use $errors on your page as array of errors.

After that you can add an error container for each input like that:

```html
.
.
...<input type="text" name="name" ....
<span class="error">
    <?php 
        if(isset($errors['name'])){
            echo $errors['name'];
        }
    ?>
</span>
```